# Git doesn't know my name/email when Github Actions deploy R package documentation and breaks

Tags: r, github-actions, pkgdown

For a while now I've been happily using Github's Actions to run my library's `R CMD check` and deploying the package's documentation. Suddenly the [package action](https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares/runs/875259918?check_suite_focus=true) started failing with the following error:

```
── Commiting updated site ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Running git add -A .
Running git commit --allow-empty -m 'Built site for lares: 4.9.0@d936943'

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'runner@Mac-1594850189701.(none)')

Error: System command 'git' failed, exit status: 128, stdout & stderr were printed

 Stack trace:

 1. pkgdown::deploy_to_branch(new_process = FALSE)
 2. pkgdown:::github_push(dest_dir, commit_message, remote, branch)
 3. pkgdown:::with_dir(dir, { ...
 4. base:::force(code)
 5. pkgdown:::git("commit", "--allow-empty", "-m", commit_message)
 6. processx::run("git", c(...), echo_cmd = echo_cmd, echo = echo,  ...
 7. throw(new_process_error(res, call = sys.call(), echo = echo,  ...

 x System command 'git' failed, exit status: 128, stdout & stderr were printed 

── Removing worktree ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Running git worktree remove \
  /var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/Rtmpp2vz58/file888686837c1
Execution halted
##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've tried running those commands with my name and email from RStudio's terminal, tried from different computers I code, checked `pkgdown::deploy_to_branch()` documentation... with no success.

Any idea how to solve this? What am I not seeing? Is it a bug on something that recently changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- run: |
       git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
       git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Just add step like that somewhere in your workflow.

In fact, it looks [you already (almost) wrote a fix](https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares/commit/8184aaec9e2f35b10c1ccdb4832316612d138a3d) but decided for some reason to use `Rscript` as shell for that, and didn't close `'`. That threw other kind of error so you [kicked it out](https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares/commit/4801acb6b28408dc8fd2d3106304b4fe144a84a8) and are back at square one :)

Comment: That's great @samira and awesome catch! I've just deployed your solution and it finally passed. Is this a one time step that can now be removed or should I leave it? I've never seen other libraries with this step so makes me wonder...

Comment: @Bernardo You should leave that in. It looks that earlier [some defaults slipped in](https://github.com/laresbernardo/lares/runs/867463561?check_suite_focus=true#step:9:225) and now GitHub decided to fix that. -- I'm guessing calling `git push` from workflow step does some voodoo to make commits appear to be from _github-actions bot_. In your case, you're using _something else_ to create a commit so it works differently... Well, at least that's best wild guess i have right now.